ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv' Python 3.12.3 in VSCode
I'm using Jupyter Notebook in VSCode which has Python 3.12.3 as interpreter.

python-dotenv==0.21.1
azure-search-documents==11.4.0
azure-storage-blob==12.19.1
azure-identity==1.15.0
these are already installed however when I am importing load_dotenv, getting the below error:

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
import os 


:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 from dotenv import load_dotenv
      2 from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
      3 from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'

I ensured the Python interpreter that I am having in jupyter notebook is Python 3.12.3.
I have tried installing latest version of Python locally however, in CMD and VSCode terminal, I  still see Python 3.7.9.

You are probably using the wrong python interpreter somewhere. You may want to add information to your question about exactly which python versions you have installed and which environments your code works in and where it doesn't.

Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the dotenv module? You can do this by running the following commands:
pip uninstall python-dotenv
pip install python-dotenv

